# kivy adding variables to the root widget

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I wanted to make a kivy programm, that gets a number from the Text Input, add one to the number and writes in the Label.

But the program did not accepted my variable as part of the root widget.

Here is the programm:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import *
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import *
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import *

kivy.lang.Builder.load_string('''
<my_layout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas:
        Color
            rgba: 10, 10, 0, 1
    Label:
        id: label0
        text: 'Wie viel Wiegt das Ei in gramm?'
        font_size: 50


    TextInput:
        id: my_textinput
        font_size: 100
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 100
    Button:
        id: my_button
        height: 100
        text: 'button'
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 20, 1
        on_press: root.berechnen(my_textinput.text)
    Label:
        id: label1
        text: root.var
''')

class my_layout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(my_layout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.var = self.number
    def berechnen(self, txt):
        self.number = txt

class Add(App):
    def build(self):
        return my_layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Add().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set self.var, but this isn't a kivy property so the gui doesn't know it's changed and doesn't set the property.

You could instead do

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class my_layout(BoxLayout):
    var = StringProperty('')
```

and otherwise proceed the same.

It also looks like your code will crash because you don't set `self.number` but you do refer to it. Maybe this is an error in pasting your example.